# Android App Crashes on Startup unknown reason

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse

When I run this code on my Nexus 5 it crashes on startup and I do not know why.

Here is a screenshot of the preview window:

[image: Screenshot]

My code:

```
MainActivity.java:

package com.example.coolfreewallpapers;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;


import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.Window;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {


ImageView display;
int toPhone;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    // check if next two lines are necessary
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); // gets rid of app title
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=11) {
           getWindow().setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_HARDWARE_ACCELERATED);
        }

    setContentView(R.layout.wallpaper);
    toPhone = R.drawable.one;

display = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVdisplay);
ImageView one = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage1);
ImageView two = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage2);
ImageView three = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage3);
ImageView four = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage4);
ImageView five = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage5);
ImageView six = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage6);
ImageView seven = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage7);
ImageView eight = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage8);
ImageView nine = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage9);
ImageView ten = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage10);
ImageView eleven = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage11);
ImageView twelve = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage12);
ImageView thirteen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage13);
ImageView fourteen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage14);
ImageView fifteen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage15);
ImageView sixteen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage16);
ImageView seventeen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage17);
ImageView eighteen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage18);
ImageView nineteen = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage19);
ImageView twenty = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage20);
ImageView twentyone = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage21);
ImageView twentytwo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage22);
ImageView twentythree = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage23);
ImageView twentyfour = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage24);
ImageView twentyfive = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage25);
ImageView twentysix = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage26);
ImageView twentyseven = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage27);
ImageView twentyeight = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage28);
ImageView twentynine = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage29);
ImageView thirty = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage30);


Button setWall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.BsetWallpaper);



one.setOnClickListener(this);
two.setOnClickListener(this);
three.setOnClickListener(this);
four.setOnClickListener(this);
five.setOnClickListener(this);
six.setOnClickListener(this);  
seven.setOnClickListener(this);  
eight.setOnClickListener(this);  
nine.setOnClickListener(this);  
ten.setOnClickListener(this);  
eleven.setOnClickListener(this); 
twelve.setOnClickListener(this);  
thirteen.setOnClickListener(this);  
fourteen.setOnClickListener(this); 
fifteen.setOnClickListener(this); 
sixteen.setOnClickListener(this);  
seventeen.setOnClickListener(this);  
eighteen.setOnClickListener(this); 
nineteen.setOnClickListener(this); 
twenty.setOnClickListener(this);
twentyone.setOnClickListener(this); 
twentytwo.setOnClickListener(this);
twentythree.setOnClickListener(this);  
twentyfour.setOnClickListener(this); 
twentyfive.setOnClickListener(this); 
twentysix.setOnClickListener(this);  
twentyseven.setOnClickListener(this);  
twentyeight.setOnClickListener(this);  
twentynine.setOnClickListener(this); 
thirty.setOnClickListener(this);  

setWall.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()){
    case R.id.IVimage1:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.one);
        toPhone = R.drawable.one;
        break;
    case R.id.IVimage2:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.two);
        toPhone = R.drawable.two;
        break;
    case R.id.IVimage3:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.three);
        toPhone = R.drawable.three;
        break;
    case R.id.IVimage4:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.four);
        toPhone = R.drawable.four;
        break;
    case R.id.IVimage5:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.five);
        toPhone = R.drawable.five;
        break;
    case R.id.IVimage6:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.six);
        toPhone = R.drawable.six;
        break;
    case R.id.IVimage7:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.seven);
        toPhone = R.drawable.seven;
        break;
    case R.id.IVimage8:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.eight);
        toPhone = R.drawable.eight;
        break;
    case R.id.IVimage9:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.nine);
        toPhone = R.drawable.nine;
        break;
    case R.id.IVimage10:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.ten);
        toPhone = R.drawable.ten;
        break;
    case R.id.IVimage11:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.eleven);
        toPhone = R.drawable.eleven;
        break;
    case R.id.IVimage12:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.twelve);
        toPhone = R.drawable.twelve;
        break;
    case R.id.IVimage13:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.thirteen);
        toPhone = R.drawable.thirteen;
        break;
    case R.id.IVimage14:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.fourteen);
        toPhone = R.drawable.fourteen;
        break;
    case R.id.IVimage15:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.fifteen);
        toPhone = R.drawable.fifteen;
        break;
    case R.id.IVimage16:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.sixteen);
        toPhone = R.drawable.sixteen;
        break;
    case R.id.IVimage17:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.seventeen);
        toPhone = R.drawable.seventeen;
        break;
    case R.id.IVimage18:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.eighteen);
        toPhone = R.drawable.eighteen;
        break;
    case R.id.IVimage19:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.nineteen);
        toPhone = R.drawable.nineteen;
        break;
    case R.id.IVimage20:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.twenty);
        toPhone = R.drawable.twenty;
        break;
    case R.id.IVimage21:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.twentyone);
        toPhone = R.drawable.twentyone;
        break;
    case R.id.IVimage22:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.twentytwo);
        toPhone = R.drawable.twentytwo;
        break;
    case R.id.IVimage23:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.twentythree);
        toPhone = R.drawable.twentythree;
        break;
    case R.id.IVimage24:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.twentyfour);
        toPhone = R.drawable.twentyfour;
        break;
    case R.id.IVimage25:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.twentyfive);
        toPhone = R.drawable.twentyfive;
        break;
    case R.id.IVimage26:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.twentysix);
        toPhone = R.drawable.twentysix;
        break;
    case R.id.IVimage27:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.twentyseven);
        toPhone = R.drawable.twentyseven;
        break;
    case R.id.IVimage28:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.twentyeight);
        toPhone = R.drawable.twentyeight;
        break;
    case R.id.IVimage29:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.twentynine);
        toPhone = R.drawable.twentynine;
        break;
    case R.id.IVimage30:
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.thirty);
        toPhone = R.drawable.thirty;
        break;


        // create method that means if low quality image is selected, 
        high quality   image is set as wallpaper


    case R.id.BsetWallpaper:
        //how to downsample
        InputStream yeaaaa  = getResources().openRawResource(toPhone);
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inSampleSize = 2; // is half the size, 4 a quarter etc..
        Bitmap whatever = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(yeaaaa, null, options);

        try {
            getApplicationContext().setWallpaper(whatever);
        }catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;

    }
}
}

AndroidManifest.xml:

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.coolfreewallpapers"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="14"
    android:targetSdkVersion="14" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/MyTheme" 
    android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        >

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>


wallpaper.xml - the only wallpaper/layout file I am using

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"  

>

<ImageView android:src="@drawable/one" android:id="@+id/IVdisplay" 
    android:layout_width="350dp" android:layout_height="350dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/imageViewDescription"
    android:layout_gravity="center"       
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:cropToPadding="true"

    android:background="@drawable/border"

     />
<!-- not sure if adjustviewBounds is needed -->

<!-- style="@style/myImageView" 
    -->

<HorizontalScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

android:layout_gravity="fill_horizontal"
android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="5dp"           
>
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"      
>

 <ImageView android:src="@drawable/one" android:id="@+id/IVimage1" 
    android:layout_width="175dp" android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/imageViewDescription"       
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"  
    android:cropToPadding="true"
    android:background="@drawable/border_images"
    android:padding="1dp"             
    />
<ImageView android:src="@drawable/two" android:id="@+id/IVimage2" 
    android:layout_width="175dp" android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/imageViewDescription"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"       
    android:cropToPadding="true"
    android:background="@drawable/border_images"
    android:padding="1dp"           
    />
<ImageView android:src="@drawable/three" android:id="@+id/IVimage3" 
    android:layout_width="175dp" android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/imageViewDescription"       
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"     
    android:cropToPadding="true"
    android:background="@drawable/border_images"
    android:padding="1dp"       
    />
<ImageView android:src="@drawable/four" android:id="@+id/IVimage4" 
    android:layout_width="175dp" android:layout_height="170dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/imageViewDescription"        
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"       
    android:cropToPadding="true"
    android:background="@drawable/border_images"
    android:padding="1dp"        
     />
</LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>

<Button
android:id="@+id/BsetWallpaper"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="45dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="2.5dp"
android:layout_marginRight="2.5dp"
android:text="@string/wallpaperbuttontext" />

</LinearLayout>

Styles:

<resources>

<!--
    Base application theme, dependent on API level. This theme is replaced
    by AppBaseTheme from res/values-vXX/styles.xml on newer devices.
-->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <!--
        Theme customizations available in newer API levels can go in
        res/values-vXX/styles.xml, while customizations related to
        backward-compatibility can go here.
    -->
</style>

<!-- Application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <!-- All customizations that are NOT specific to a particular API-level can go
here. -->
</style>
<!-- Holo no title bar theme -->
<style parent="android:Theme.Holo" name="MyTheme">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

I've already tried Project>Clean and restarted eclipse several times but so far it hasn't helped

I've left out 25 other ImageViews which are identical to the ones I've posted except for the increasing numbers. But I am certain these are correct. Any suggestions would be appreciated

EDIT:

Here is the LogCat from Eclipse:

```
07-30 05:49:51.814: E/AndroidRuntime(11305): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-30 05:49:51.814: E/AndroidRuntime(11305): Process: com.example.coolfreewallpapers, PID: 11305
07-30 05:49:51.814: E/AndroidRuntime(11305): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.coolfreewallpapers/com.example.coolfreewallpapers.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #233: Error inflating class <unknown>
07-30 05:49:51.814: E/AndroidRuntime(11305):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2184)
07-30 05:49:51.814: E/AndroidRuntime(11305):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233)
07-30 05:49:51.814: E/AndroidRuntime(11305):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135)
07-30 05:49:51.814: E/AndroidRuntime(11305):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196)
07-30 05:49:51.814: E/AndroidRuntime(11305):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
07-30 05:49:51.814: E/AndroidRuntime(11305):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
07-30 05:49:51.814: E/AndroidRuntime(11305):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
07-30 05:49:51.814: E/AndroidRuntime(11305):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-30 05:49:51.814: E/AndroidRuntime(11305):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
07-30 05:49:51.814: E/AndroidRuntime(11305):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
07-30 05:49:51.814: E/AndroidRuntime(11305):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
07-30 05:49:51.814: E/AndroidRuntime(11305):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-30 05:49:51.814: E/AndroidRuntime(11305): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #233: Error inflating class <unknown>
07-30 05:49:51.814: E/AndroidRuntime(11305):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:620)
07-30 05:49:51.814: E/AndroidRuntime(11305):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
07-30 05:49:51.814: E/AndroidRuntime(11305):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.onCreateView(LayoutInflater.java:669)
07-30 05:49:51.814: E/AndroidRuntime(11305):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:694)
07-30 05:49:51.814: E/AndroidRuntime(11305):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:755)
07-30 05:49:51.814: E/AndroidRuntime(11305):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
07-30 05:49:51.814: E/AndroidRuntime(11305):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:758)
07-30 05:49:51.814: E/AndroidRuntime(11305):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
07-30 05:49:51.814: E/AndroidRuntime(11305):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:397)
07-30 05:49:51.814: E/AndroidRuntime(11305):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
07-30 05:49:51.814: E/AndroidRuntime(11305):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:290)
07-30 05:49:51.814: E/AndroidRuntime(11305):    at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1929)
07-30 05:49:51.814: E/AndroidRuntime(11305):    at com.example.coolfreewallpapers.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:38)
07-30 05:49:51.814: E/AndroidRuntime(11305):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
07-30 05:49:51.814: E/AndroidRuntime(11305):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
07-30 05:49:51.814: E/AndroidRuntime(11305):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
07-30 05:49:51.814: E/AndroidRuntime(11305):    ... 11 more
07-30 05:49:51.814: E/AndroidRuntime(11305): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
07-30 05:49:51.814: E/AndroidRuntime(11305):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
07-30 05:49:51.814: E/AndroidRuntime(11305):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
07-30 05:49:51.814: E/AndroidRuntime(11305):    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:594)
07-30 05:49:51.814: E/AndroidRuntime(11305):    ... 26 more
07-30 05:49:51.814: E/AndroidRuntime(11305): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
07-30 05:49:51.814: E/AndroidRuntime(11305):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeAsset(Native Method)
07-30 05:49:51.814: E/AndroidRuntime(11305):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:594)
07-30 05:49:51.814: E/AndroidRuntime(11305):    at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:429)
07-30 05:49:51.814: E/AndroidRuntime(11305):    at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:840)
07-30 05:49:51.814: E/AndroidRuntime(11305):    at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2110)
07-30 05:49:51.814: E/AndroidRuntime(11305):    at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:602)
07-30 05:49:51.814: E/AndroidRuntime(11305):    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:129)
07-30 05:49:51.814: E/AndroidRuntime(11305):    at android.widget.ImageView.<init>(ImageView.java:119)
07-30 05:49:51.814: E/AndroidRuntime(11305):    ... 29 more
```

Does this help explain anything?

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling the app from the emulator? It could be some weird cached issue.

Comment: I'm not using the emulator. I'm using a Nexus 5 physical device since it's usually MUCH faster.

Comment: Same issue. And you can use intel Hax to speed up the emulator.

Comment: Well the app worked perfectly around 30mins ago. Then eclipsed crashed because of a memory error.

Comment: As in OutOfMemoryException?

Comment: I believe so, it then asked if I wanted to close the workbench? Is that the same error?

Comment: Restarted eclipse, no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like your image is corrupted. Delete it from the drawable folder and replace it with a new one.

I've had a similar issue before. It was due to a corrupted image file. I don't know why android reported the ImageView class could not be found and I haven't had any desire to dig through the source code to find out but that's what it was for me.

Comment: Already tried that with both the images and the ic_launcher.png files from each drawable folder

Answer (score 0):

**Out of memory bound Exception**

This exception of out of memory bound

remove all line of xml android:background="@drawable/" and android:src="@drawable/" of ImageView

or

reduce size of drawable images

Comment: Surely that'll mean I can't view the images?

Comment: please add line android:background="@drawable/" or android:src="@drawable/"  but reduce size of drawable all images like one ,two... thirty